# Installation of Automatically Tuned Linear Algebra Software, generic static

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

While installing ATLAS from [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libatlas-base-dev/). I am facing this problem:

```
Package dependencies cannot be resolved
This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable.
Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.
```

I don't know how to go about resolving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
```

Automatically Tuned Linear Algebra Software, generic static
ATLAS is an approach for the automatic generation and optimization of numerical software. Currently ATLAS supplies optimized versions for the complete set of linear algebra kernels known as the Basic Linear Algebra Subroutines (BLAS), and a subset of the linear algebra routines in the LAPACK library.